# SAMBA netstat local address 0.0.0.0

Tags: domain-name-system, samba, samba4, netstat

Trying to run samba AD DC but I'm stuck. After created domain provision, I defined resolv.conf:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.99.0.30
search example.com
```

Service running:

```
samba-ad-dc.service - Samba Active Directory Domain Controller
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running)
```

Queries of DNS records seems fine:

```
$ host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.random.example.com has SRV record 0 100 389 random.example.com.

$ host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.example.com.
_kerberos._udp.random.example.com has SRV record 0 100 88 random.example.com.

$ host -t A random.example.com.
dc1.random.example.com has address 10.99.0.30
```

When i do netstat:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep ":53"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      34599/samba: task[d
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      34599/samba: task[d
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           34599/samba: task[d
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           745/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                34599/samba: task[d
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                745/avahi-daemon: r
```

Should be local address in netstat exact IP address of DNS(local) 10.99.0.30 like 10.99.0.30:53 ?

When i tried to join AD from WINDOWS host I've got :

```
- The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.example.com
- The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
  (no Active Directory Domain Controllers found)
- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to 
  their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.
- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

I could not even resovle example.com by ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netstat local address was fine, it can be resolved even with 0.0.0.0:53 (listen on any IPv4 address on that server) [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139938/meaning-of-netstat-local-address-column)

I solved problem by configurating firewall according to this [page](https://linuxconfig.org/install-samba-on-redhat-8) section "Configuring the firewall". You have to add samba-dc service to your zone. You can list which ports you will open and then make them persistent:

```
firewall-cmd --info-service samba-dc
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=samba-dc
```

Reload firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Verify (look for samba-dc):

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

PS: I thought it would be a problem with firewall but in [samba install instructions](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller#Configuring_the_DNS_Resolver) is nothing about firewall configuration.